# Different Uses For HashMap

Tags: data-structures, programming-languages, hashmap

I've been familiar with HashMaps for years. In java I use them like associative arrays, in ActionScript I've used them for a handful of interesting tricks(see example below). It's pretty rare that I need to use an Object as a key and I was wondering if anyone had interesting examples where you are using HashMaps with Object as keys. Please answer in your language of choice, this question is not about any specific language.

*I'm well aware that in some languages String, Int etc are Objects*

**ActionScript Example :** *Stores values related to an Object without altering the interface of the Object.*

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
// dictionary is like a HashMap in AS
var lookup:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
lookup[s] = someValue;
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(evt:Event):void{
  trace(lookup[evt.currentTarget]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use value objects as keys when I have a complex key; this would be analogous to having a primary key in a database table with more than one column. For example, suppose you have a college course with multiple sections. In Java, you might have a value object like:

```
class Section {
   private String courseName;
   private int sectionNumber;
   ...
}
```

with getters, setters, equals(), and hashCode(). You could potentially have other properties on the value object as well, but if equals and hashCode are written using those two properties, you can use Section as a map key.

I've seen some people simple concatenate the fields they want as the key into a string, like `String key = course + Integer.toString(section);`, but as far as I'm concerned, it is much more expressive to use `map.put(section, students)` than `map.put(section.getCourseName() + Integer.toString(section.getSectionNumber()))`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the definition of equality for the keys. If equality means object identity (same memory address) then any object will do. If key equality depends on the objects internal state, then most libraries suggest you provide a meaningful implementation of `hash()`. Python also requires to know that the objects used as keys are [immutable](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) so the invariants can't be broken by modification of a key after it has been added to a map. Pythons definition of equality regarding keys is deep-compare. In other languages/libraries the inherent requirements about invariants, equality, hashing and immutability are the same, but they are not enforced.

Comment: +1 thanks for the feedback. It's interesting that Python uses deep compare, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Zevan it can use deep-compare because it allows only up to tuples of known immutable types, which are all basic and efficient-to-compare.